# Using ArcPy Update Cursor with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor

I am trying to do an update cursor in my script. Can someone please tell me why when I do 2 IF statements only the second IF statement runs.

For example this runs fine

```
fc = CAD_WA
fields = ["LAND_TYPE", "LAND_NAME", "LOTNO", "LotNo_F" ]

# Create update cursor for feature class
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:

    for row in cursor:

        if row[0] == "RESVE":
            row[3] = row[1]

            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

But if I do this expression only the second if statment runs. Why?

```
fc = CAD_WA
fields = ["LAND_TYPE", "LAND_NAME", "LOTNO", "LotNo_F" ]

# Create update cursor for feature class
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:

    for row in cursor:

        if row[0] == "RESVE":
            row[3] = row[1]
        if row[1] == "UCL":
            row[3] = row[1]

            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: How do you know only the second if statement is executed, when the results of the code you show will be the same `row[3] = row[1]`? Maybe both if statements are setting row[3] to row[1]

Comment: In the second code block, the `cursor.updateRow()` is only executed with the second `if` statement, as per the indentation rules of Python.

Comment: Thanks @Vince it works now. Oh so simple. Think i need to do some Indention reading.

Comment: In this case, you could `or` the two conditions, otherwise you could place the `updateRow` inside each `if`, or use an `elif` cascade, with an `else: continue` then an unintended update. But you don't want to update every row if it isn't actually changed.